# Пакет данных с динамическим размером

Tags: c, структуры, динамические-массивы, пакет

В современном мире не обойтись от передачи данных в пакетах. Проблема настигшая меня в данном вопросе стоит в следующем, есть структура с полем `uint8_t*` , размер массива будет вычислен в ходе запуска и как же тогда быть, как сформировать пакет ведь если вернуть просто структуру то там будет указатель на массив а не данные находящиеся в массиве. Приведу пример самой структуры и функции формирующей пакет на языке си.

```
typdef struct{
  uint8_t preambula;
  uint8_t count_error;
  uint8_t* errors;
} help;


help* make_help(uint8_t pre,uint8_t cEr,uint8_t* mass)
{
  help* pack = (help*)malloc(sizeof(help)+cEr);
  pack->preambula = pre;
  pack->count_error = cEr;
  pack->errors = (uint8_t*)malloc(cEr);
  memcpy(pack->errors,mass,cEr);
  return (pack); // Так будет некорректно так как вернется указатель а на 
                 // другой машине в данной области совсем другие данные
}
```

Comment: Глупость какая-то. Как он попадет на другую машину? С этого надо начинать.

Comment: Ссылки не передаются на другую машину. Для передачи данных используется, например, сериализация. Либо данные перепаковываются в вид... например  `struct{ uint8_t preambula;
    uint8_t count_error;
    uint8_t errors[1]`

Comment: При динамическом размере пакета просто добавляете перед данными дополнительное поле - длину этих данных

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема эта старше интернета :-) Потому, как обмен пакетами по сети появился до рождения интернета и даже IP протокола. Конкретно:

Откройте описание ЛЮБОГО двоичного протокола. Например: RFC 768 — Протокол датаграмм клиента (UDP). Там будет описание заголовка типа такого:

```
    0      7 8     15 16    23 24    31
   +--------+--------+--------+--------+
   |      Порт       |      Порт       |
   |   Отправителя   |   Получателя    |
   +--------+--------+--------+--------+
   |                 |  Контрольная    |
   |      Длина      |       сумма     |
   +--------+--------+--------+--------+
   |
   |       октеты данных  ...
   +---------------- ...
```

В то же время, известно, что:

> Чтобы избежать фрагментации UDP пакетов (и возможной их потери),
>   размер данных в UDP не должен превышать: MTU — (Max IP Header Size) —
>   (UDP Header Size) = 1500 — 60 — 8 = 1432 байт

Т.е. размер поля данных в любом пакете всегда ограничивается некоей разумной границей. Возвращаясь к Вашему вопросу. Попробуйте переписать код как-то так:

```
#define MAX_DATA_SIZE 2048
typdef struct{
  uint8_t preambula;
  uint8_t count_error;
  uint8_t errors[MAX_DATA_SIZE];
} help;
```

При этом, массив *errors* будет содержать реально только *count_error* заполненных элементов. А  при передаче пакета по сети Вы будете указывать его **реальную**  длину, расчитанную, исходя из *count_error*.

Ну а с потерей небольшого кусочка памяти, при выделении по максимуму,  надо просто смириться :-)